# Huge security risk using TFS build system

Tags: tfs, msbuild, build-server

turns out that tfs build system always use the same Build Account to get the latest source code and do the build job. And this account has the highest permission to access all the source code.

So anyone who has just one single team project build permission can actually get the source code of all team projects by creating a build definition, and set 'Source Setting' to root of TeamProjectCollection, then in MSBuild post event, do 'XCopy' to move the source code to any remote server.

Comment: +1 Interesting, I'd like to hear the answers to this.

Answer (score 0):

The build server is associated on a team project basis. Allowing multiple projects to use the same build server is an implementation decision not an inherent security flaw, if security segregation is important use multiple build servers with different accounts. For Team build account to team project setup details see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253062(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253062%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: I know this workaround, even so, this should be a big design flaw. Why not run under the account who create the team build definition? Or specify one account, which is flexible. Using one single high permission account is definitely an issue.

Comment: Not a workaround, the security model is a granular as it needs to be it is up to the tfs administrator to set the system up correctly to reflect the security concerns of the organization. The analogy would be having multiple doors and deciding to put the same lock on all the doors. Not an inherent security flaw but an implementation decision made by the person configuring tfs. And if you are that concerned with developers stealing code you have bigger problems that software won't fix

Comment: The build server is not associated on a team project basis. It's associated on a collection basis. So with a basic setup of a build service every developer is able to run code in a unittest executed on that build server using the permissions of the build account. The build account is by default having access to the whole collection. So every developer is able to get the source of all projects in the whole collection. And much more! I wrote a lot of server plugins to force the assignment of a single build service to a single team project..

Comment: @MikeBeeler Still, "Why not run under the account who create the team build definition? Or specify one running account, which is flexible". Isn't that much more reasonable?

Comment: @KevinYang This is technical not possible. If a build server should run under the users account, it must get the account and password somewhere. This would be even more insecure.

Comment: @MikeBeeler actually it's not that unsafe. In windows task scheduler, we often setup a task which is run under specific domain account. Password is input once, and saved by Windows Credential manager, which i think is encrypted. TFS can use the same technique, this should not be a problem.

Comment: The security level is up to you, trust your developers with your source code or not. TFS lets you be as granular with the security as you need to be in order to solve Business security requirements. Some collections may use the same build server others may not. The service password is one that is set when the build controller software is installed on the server that will build the software. Therefor TFS knows the password because the account is visible to the domain. I'm not the one that is claiming that the practice either way is unsafe. you are.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. And it's bad :(

From the docs of microsoft, they tell you , that a developer is seen as a trusted entity. That's their rationale:

```
Installing Team Foundation Build Service increases the attack surface of the computer. Because developers are treated as trusted entities in the build system, a malicious user could, for example, construct a build definition to run arbitrary code that is designed to take control of the server and steal data from Team Foundation Server. Customers are encouraged to follow security best practices as well as deploy defense in-depth measures to ensure that their build environment is secure. This includes developer workstations. For more information regarding security best practices, see the TechNet Article Security Guidance.
```

Here is the [original article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181712.aspx).

So when using a build server, you're always at risk!
As I mentioned in a comment. I wrote a lot of server side plugins and so on to secure the tfs environment of a large company. It's a lot of work to get a tfs build environment secure.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to revoke the privilege to create and edit Build Definitions so you have a strict control on which build is run where.

Comment: This does not help as long as unittest are run within a build.

Comment: It does if you address each Build to the proper server.

Comment: As long as build job is run by one single account, this problem can not be solved by one single build controller.

Comment: @GiulioVian your solution is similar with the one provided by MikeBeeler, which require one build server per team project.

Comment: "It does if you address each Build to the proper server. " <-- no a developer can choose a different build server when queuing a build. There is no possibility to prevent developers from choosing a different build server using the standard tools provided.

Comment: In the build definition you can set a specific controller and limit the agent select. The result can narrow to a single agent, in which case code running in the build is limited to a single machine. So it is a PIA for the TFS Admin and @KevinYang yes it is similar to Beeler's suggestion